# MicrosoftTeams Powershell - OAuth (Non interactive)

Tags: windows, powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to create a Non interactive script to connect to Teams in Powershell for accounts with MFA.

It all works but i receive the error

```
Connect-MicrosoftTeams : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
```

This error occurs on the connect

```
....
$token_graph = "MY ACCESS TOKEN"
$token_teams = "MY ACCESS TOKEN"
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AccessTokens @($token_graph,$token_teams) -AccountId MYACCID
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I tried to `Connect-MicrosoftTeams` without using Account ID  :

[image]

So The cmdlet  `_TeamsEnvironmentName_`  and  _`ApplicationId/CertificateThumbprint_`  parameters are on different parameter sets, so we can not use them on the same cmdlet run based on this  [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/connect-microsoftteams?view=teams-ps)   .

To use this Please visit the Teams Product Group   [Teams UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/)  .

Reference:- https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-docs-powershell/issues/4855

For more information please refer the below link:-

. [Powershell Connect to MicrosoftTeams with MFA user |MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/407082/powershell-connect-to-microsoftteams-with-mfa-user.html) .

Answer (score 0):

It will take your windows teams app authentication only.